# can I bind a value to a part of an object from elsewhere in the model?

Tags: data-binding, angularjs

I have a model that has (for example) shopping cart item IDs and a list of available items to add to the cart. It's a fake example.

```
  table#items 
    tbody
      tr(ng-repeat="item in cart.items")
        td.hide {{item.id}}
        td {{availableItems.where(id: item.id).first.name}} <-- pseudo code 
        td ({{item.shippingType}})
```

What I'd like to do is bind the second cell to the name of the item from the list of available items, rather than cluttering up the model by having that value in 2 places. Would I use a filter function to do this? [The docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) are very simplistic. How can I pass `item.id` to the filter function?

I've gotten closer with this in the markup:

```
td {{availableDatasources | filter: itemNameById}}
```

and this in the scope:

```
$scope.itemNameById= function(item) {
  lodash($scope.availableItems).find({
      id: item.id
    }).name;
};
```

Only problem is I don't get a name back (even though that's what the filter seems to be returning) -- I get all of the available items. It's hitting the filter code but the filter seems to not be filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I'm not sure this is worthwhile.  Your cart is probably just an array of references to objects in your availableItems array, so you're not really repeating anything.

But if I wanted to do as you say, I would include underscore.js in my project.

http://underscorejs.org/

Then in the controller, I would add underscore to the scope:

```
$scope._ = _;
```

In my template I would write

```
td {{_.findWhere(availableItems, {id: item.id}).name}}
```

Or, more likely, I would add a more specific function to my scope:

```
$scope.productFromId = 
     function(id) { return _.findWhere($scope.availableItems, {id: id});};
```

And then in the template:

```
td {{productFromId(item.id).name}}
```

Comment: You should be able to use the same basic form but use Lo-Dash instead of underscore.. they look similar.

Comment: Yeah I already have lodash in my project so I was gonna use that. This looks like it will work for my purposes. `filter` wasn't what I needed, I just needed to make a find function like  you suggest. Why do you think it's not worthwhile? I don't see a reason to put the name of the product in 2 different places.

Comment: I'm saying that if your "cart" variable were just an array of references to objects in your "availableItems" array, it wouldn't really be in 2 different places.